# Machine crashes after upgrading Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, google-compute-engine

I'm experimenting with Google Compute Engine at Google Cloud.

I've setup a basic LAMP environment in one of the preinstalled Ubuntu images offered by Google, in this case, the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (amd64 trusty image built on 2016-01-14).

The soft I installed is exactly the same I've already installed in many other servers from Digital Ocean and also a Virtual Box in my home.

The machine I choose was a 1 vCPU (f1-micro) with just 0,6 GB of RAM, which was fine for the light work they managed.

After upgrading the system with apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, the system just crashed and it never booted again. I've stopped and restarted the instance many times, but it was dead, with its CPU at 400% of use when trying to reboot.

The errors I've got after the intent of upgrading were:

```
Fetched 24.6 MB in 1s (13.2 MB/s)
(Reading database ... 144753 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.127.20_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.127.20) over (1.127.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-4.9-base_4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.9-base:amd64 (4.9.3-0ubuntu4) over (4.9.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcc-4.9-base:amd64 (4.9.3-0ubuntu4) ...
(Reading database ... 144753 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc1_1%3a4.9.3-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc1:amd64 (1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4) over (1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgcc1:amd64 (1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
(Reading database ... 144753 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.92.37.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking software-properties-common (0.92.37.7) over (0.92.37.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.92.37.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-software-properties (0.92.37.7) over (0.92.37.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../kpartx_0.4.9-3ubuntu7.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kpartx (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.7) over (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic (3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic (3.19.0-47.53~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-firmware (1.127.20) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty:
 linux-imNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                             age-hwe-generic-trusty depends on linux-image-generic-lts-utopic; however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-hwe-generic-trusty:
 linux-hwe-generic-trusty depends on linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty; however:
  Package linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-hwe-generic-trusty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-vivid:
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid depends on linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-vivid (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.92.37.7) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.92.37.7) ...
Setting up kpartx (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic
 linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
 linux-image-hwe-generic-trusty
 linux-hwe-generic-trusty
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-47-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone has a similar problem? 
What should I blame? the amount of RAM, the original image, the processor too small, the Google Machines?

I like what I've seen of Google Cloud Machines, but I can't put both steps in while I'm not sure if they can crash this way at any time. before this experience, all virtual machines were like solid rock and never crashed even after fierces installings and uninstalling of any kind of soft. This one crashed with almost nothing in it.

Thank you in advance for your opinions.

NEW DETAILS:
I've recovered the machine form an image previous to the crash. Now I could upgrade the system, but there are still errors present after upgrading. I don't know if I can trust in the integrity of this system now:

```
12 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic (3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-49-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic
xz: (stdin): Cannot allocate memory
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 xz -8 --check=crc32 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-59-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-60-generic (3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
```

Comment: Updates: I've tried again over the snaphot I took before the upgrade, and it didn't crashed. May be the original crash was after a second intent of upgrading.

Comment: Is it possible to retry with the new Ubuntu image build?

Comment: I've retried and it works, but each time I made an upgrade, it took a lot of time and throw the errors I posted above ("running depmode" a lot of times). Then, I made a apt-get autoremove, and the machine crashed again forever. I've actually give up. I'll try another platform, perhaps Amazon.

Comment: I just spun up a test instance using the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
amd64 trusty image built on 2016-02-22, and the upgrade is working totally fine. Did you have the chance to try using the same image?

Comment: As I said, I started with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (amd64 trusty image built on 2016-01-14). Perhaps it's a problem related to that image. Anyway, I can't trust in the Google system in general. They even don't provide support, except that you pay an extra for that.

Comment: The image that you are using is already a deprecated image and if it has bug, it might not get fixed as another image built on 2016-02-22 has been launched which might have the fix for the issue you were encountering.

Comment: As a heads up, Google engineers always monitor the threads on StackOverflow  Google Groups and ServerFault, in order to provide best effort support to the customers.

Comment: Well, it happened a month ago and I didn't receive any answer from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic updates are configured in "unattended-upgrade".

To disable;

comment out the `Allowed-Origins` of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file

and/or add:

```
"APT :: Periodic :: Unattended-Upgrade" 0 lines ";"
```

in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file

Comment: I'm sorry, but disabling upgrades is not an option to me. Upgrades should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If `update-initramfs` is running out of memory (I ran into this on a google-cloud instance with 600 MB of ram), try:

`export XZ_DEFAULTS="--memlimit=80MiB"`

Then re-try `apt-get upgrade` (or `dpkg --configure -a`).

You may want add that in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` so that it gets used when `unattended-upgrades` runs.

Source: https://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2016/01/msg00032.html